# Smartphone browser emulator

Tags: responsive-design, emulation, smartphone

Im trying to test my website on different kind of devices, for example iphone, tablets or androids. The problem is i do not have access to all of those devices and every so called online emulator doesnt really emulate anything else besides resolution.

So say iphone related issue doesnt appear on my computer.

My question would be whats the best paid or free service that would provide me the tools needed to test my website on as many different devices as possible?

Just to name a few so far i tried:

http://mobiletest.me/
http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/
http://www.brickandmobile.com/mobile-emulator/

None of them displayed same issues that im having on the actuall device.

Comment: Have you tried this one? http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 1):

For Android, you can install the [SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), which includes a [device emulator](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) that runs Android in (basically) a virtual machine.  This virtualized copy of Android includes the browser, so you can use it for testing your site.  You can create virtual Android devices with a variety of screen sizes, so you can test your design on both phones and tablets.

Note that if you want decent performance from the emulator, you should configure it to run an x86 system image (as opposed to ARM), and install the [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) add-on (available through the SDK manager app) that enables the emulator to use your processor's virtualization support.  This allows the emulator to run the Android system directly on your real processor, instead of having to emulate a processor.  You should also enable the "use host GPU" option so that graphics in the emulated Android device can be hardware-accelerated instead of rendered in software.